# How do I encode params for posting with curl from Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, encoding, curl

I am using Pommo for my mailing list, unfortunatelly Pommo doesn't provide an HTTP API but provides and embedable subscription form I can put on my site. But posting using that form takes me out of my site and that is unacceptable for me.

So I want to do the field validation in Rails and then use curl to post the values.

The fields Pommo generates looks like this:

```
   <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="60" name="Email" id="email" value="" />
   <input type="text" size="32" name="d[1]" id="field1" />
   <input type="text" size="32" name="d[2]" id="field2" />
   <input type="text" size="32" name="d[3]" id="field3" value="México" />
```

Which produces the following params in Rails:

```
   { "d"=>{"1"=>"Macario", "2"=>"Ortega", "3"=>"México", "5"=>""}, "Email" => mail@example.com ... }
```

Now I can validate the format of the email and if the required fields are present but I don't know how to encode this hash as string for posting using curl.

Is this kind of data structure encoding standar or dependant on application?
Does it has a name?

Answer (score 9):

ActiveSupport (available for free under Rails) provides a handy to_param method.

```
{
  "d" => {
    "1" => "Macario",
    "2" => "Ortega",
    "3" => "Mxico",
    "5" => ""
  },
  "Email" => "mail@example.com"
}.to_param
# => "Email=mail%40example.com&d%5B1%5D=Macario&d%5B2%5D=Ortega&d%5B3%5D=Mxico&d%5B5%5D="
```

Answer (score 2):

That format is created by Rails with the function normalize_params.  Basically it recursively interprets [] as hashes.  You can find the code at the [Rails API page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html#M000560).

Here is a very rough sample function to undo it for your case:

```
def create_post_params(params, base = "")
  toreturn = ''
  params.each_key do |key|
    keystring = base.blank? ? key : "#{base}[#{key}]"
    toreturn << (params[key].class == Hash ? create_post_params(params[key], keystring) : "#{keystring}=#{CGI.escape(params[key])}&")
  end
  toreturn
end
```

I haven't really tested it, but it does about what you want.  You can then use it with something like curl.  But you can also use the built in Ruby Net::HTTP lib.
Something like:

```
@server = URI.parse(server_url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(@server.host, @server.port)
http.use_ssl = @server.is_a?(URI::HTTPS)
result = http.post(@server.path + "PATH TO METHOD IN SERVER", create_post_params(params), SOME_HEADER_OPTIONS)
```

I would also recommend you looking at a project called [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master).  It is a library to make easy HTTP API classes for services.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do an HTTP post from inside your rails application

http = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', '3030')
   result = http.post('/process_email_form', form_param_hash).

You can validate this approach by viewing the HTTP Header and parameter information generated from the Pommo form against what you internal application posts

Answer (score 0):

That'll be called a "serialization" [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), and in this case, it's most likely dependent on Rails (I come from a PHP background).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function to do it by hand, I just wrote this

```
 def encode_parameters(params, base = [])
   params.delete_if { |k,v| [ :method, :action, :controller ].include?(k.to_s.intern) }.map do |k,v|
     if v.is_a?(Hash) 
       encode_parameters(v, base.clone.push(k))
     else
       base.length == 0 ? "#{CGI::escape(k.to_s)}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" : "#{CGI::escape(base[0].to_s)}#{base.slice(1, base.length).map { |b| CGI::escape("[#{b.to_s}]")}.join("") }#{CGI::escape("[#{k.to_s}]")}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}"
     end
   end.join("&")
 end
```

Enjoy!